# Insert data manually in a safe way?

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger which needs to fill a table with hundreds of rows, I need to type every single insert manually (it is a kind of pre-config table).
This table has an Int FK to an Enum Table. The Enum Table uses an int as a PK and a `varchar` (which is UNIQUE).

While typing the insert statements I need to be very careful that the integer FK is the correct one.
I would rather like to insert the data by the varchar of the enum.
So I do something like this now:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ColorId)
VALUES(1)
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ColorStr)
VALUES('Red')
```

The reason why the Enum has an int PK is because of performance issues (fast queries), but I don't know if it is a good idea now. What do you think?

Is there a safe way to do it? Is it possible to insert data into a Table View?

Comment: You could set an Identity on on the int, do inserts of just your varchars, then disable identity on the int column. You would just have to run your inserts in a specific order if the string had to match to a specific int.

Comment: Do you have a table that stores the colors with name and ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Do not insert.

No joke.

First, you do not need to use one insert statement PER LINE - look at the syntax, you can have one insert statement doing a lot of lines.

Second, nothing in the world says you can not do processing (like select and join) on the inserted data.

I generally use table definition like this (with a merge statement) for all my static lookup library data (like country lists). Full automatic maintenance on every change. WIth inserts and updates happening on demand.